# split string by newline and space

Tags: java, string, split

I have some string e.g.

```
 "Some\n\nstring\n\n \n\nSome\n\ntext"
```

I want to split this string by `"\n\n \n\n"`, but its not working.

```
String[] splited=str.split("\n\n \n\n");
```

it doesn't split in two difeerent parts, only one part.

Comment: Your code should work, see https://ideone.com/LAx1jc. Perhaps, you have `\r\n` endings. Then add `\r` to the `split` pattern argument.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, there isnt any \r

Comment: What about the literal space? Are you sure there is only one? Try replacing the space with `[\\p{Zs}\t]+` / `[\\s&&[^\r\n]]+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i just replaced it with"\\n\\n\\s\\n\\n" and it worked

Comment: But it does not make sense given the sample string you posted. The question is off-topic for now. A literal space should work for the string above, too. Please update (copy/paste) the real input string you have in the question. Is there a tab?

Comment: Please update the question so that it could be answered.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew there is no tab for sure.

Comment: Copy/paste the *real* string into the question. Otherwise, your question must be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
String[] splited= str.split("\\W+");
```

[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/LPxfuL)